# vb.net why after a form is closed, class members still occupy memory?

Tags: vb.net, garbage-collection

I define some global variables of a class as follows:

```
Private Class MyClass
Private var1 as Decimal
Private list1 as List(Of string)
Private list2 as List(Of string)
....'Subs here
End Class
```

But I found that after this form is closed, all above variables, var1, list1, list2 still exist in memory. I thought they should be collected by gc since the form is already disposed as I confirmed.

Add: I have monitored half an hour after the form is closed. But these variables are not collected by gc. I have an automatic update procedure on the form which uses above variables. Since the above variables still hold values, the automatic update procedure is always called which causes exception. (One quick fix is to check if form.isDisposed in update procedure. But I do not think this is elegeant. Besides, these variables occupy memory.)

Thanks

Comment: Dispose does not mean something will be immediately GC'ed and removed from memory.

Comment: Garbage collection doesn't always happen immediately so things may hang around until the GC runs. If these variables aren't referenced elsewhere, they're probably flagged and will clear out on the next run.

Comment: Recommended read: [Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx).

Comment: **Do not** call `GC.Collect()` manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I found that after this form is closed, all above variables, var1, list1, list2 still exist in memory.

This is expected behavior; garbage collection is non-deterministic, meaning that you can't predict exactly when the memory claimed by an object will be recycled. Garbage collection is an expensive process, and the algorithm is intelligent enough to delay it until absolutely necessary (i.e., when you're starved for memory).

> I thought they should be collected by gc since the form is already disposed as I confirmed.

The form doesn't get disposed unless you call the `Dispose` method explicitly, or wrap its creation in a `using` statement. But that still won't "solve" the problem you're citing because even once the object is disposed, the memory used by its members is not immediately reclaimed. Disposal is required to release *unmanaged* resources; you're talking here about *managed* ones.

It's not at all clear to me what the *actual* problem you're trying to solve is. Is your computer running out of memory? Are you getting out of memory errors when you try to create new objects in your code? If not, why are you so worried about when your objects get freed? That's the whole point of a garbage collected environment: to free you from having to worry about these things.

I'm also not sure what tools you're using to inspect the data stored in those memory locations, but if it's the Visual Studio debugger, you're getting erroneous information. When running under the debugger, object lifetimes are actually extended so that you can check their values.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio debugger. I have an automatic update procedure on the form which uses above variables. Since the above variables still hold values after the form is closed, the automatic update procedure is always called which causes exception. (One quick fix is to check if form.isDisposed in update procedure. But I do not think this is elegeant. Besides, these variables occupy memory.)

Comment: @Summer: Okay, how does your automatic update procedure work? Does it check for sentinel values? Just set those values when your form gets disposed.

Comment: Automatic update procedure checks global variables, such as var1, list1 I defined in question. Do you mean that I set these values to nothing in Dispose in designer? Or I can simply check if form.isDisposed in automatic update procedure?

Comment: @Summer: Yes, you could check the [`IsDisposed` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isdisposed.aspx). In fact, as the documentation says: *"When this property returns true, the control is disposed of and can no longer be referenced as a valid Windows control. Even though the instance of a control is disposed of, it is still maintained in memory until it is removed from memory through garbage collection."* As far as the first part of your response, I'm not really sure what you mean. There are no global variables, unless you're talking about a module?

Comment: I am bad at some basic concepts. What do you call var1 that is defined in my question: Private var1 as Decimal

Answer (score 2):

Using garbage collection implies that there is garbage. That's what you are seeing.

A memory management system that counts references can remove objects immediately when they are not referenced any more, but that also means that the cost of removing them comes at that time.

In a system using garbage collection, that cost comes at specific intervals, and is a lower cost per object as it removes a lot of objects at once. Between the garbage collections, unused objects remain in memory.

Also, not every garbage collection removes every unused objects. There are different levels of garbage collection, where the most common only collects short lived objects that became unused.